# Converting a PHP Array to JSON using TypeScript/JS

Tags: php, json, typescript, type-conversion

I am doing an API call and get a response in PHP code. The issue is that I'm using TypeScript/JS and don't want to mix in PHP code in to the project.

I get a PHP array in the following format:

```
Array
(
    [hittype] => singlehit
    [singlehit] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

And I would very much like to be able to convert this response to JSON by using TypeScript or JS.
Anyone have idea or tips?

Comment: _"and get a response in PHP code"_ - that is not PHP code, that is the result of a `print_r` - debug output. Whoever tried to sell you this as a _proper_ API response, lied to you. Tell them to go fix their stuff, and respond with proper JSON.

Comment: @CBroe thanks. Never worked with PHP so had no idea, thanks for clarifying. I know it's not a proper API response and I know I have no way of getting it as JSON. But I managed to write some regex and `.replace()` to "convert" it to JSON.